# Pass single OR multiple URI segments to function (code igniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

Currently I have this url to view an image from the db (codeigniter) `domain.com/view/id`

I'd like to be able to accept multiple ids comma separated `domain.com/view/id,id,id`

Any idea how to go about it? Thanks

---

view controller part:

```
function view() {
    $id = alphaID($this->uri->segment(1) ,true);

    $this->load->model('Site_model');
    if($query = $this->Site_model->get_images($id)) {
        $data['records'] = $query;
    }   
    $this->load->view('view', $data);


}

<?php if(isset($records)) : foreach($records as $row) : ?>
    <?php if($row->alpha_id == $this->uri->segment(1)): ?>
        <h1><?php echo $row->alpha_id.$row->file_ext; ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you just pass it as `domain.com/view/id/id/id` and get the URI segments for each ID?

Comment: id like comma seperated or : symbol, for ocd reasons

Comment: @user1072983 its a better way to pass id as views/id/id/id... and use the variable arguments in php to get all of the ids

Comment: ok i'll try that way. if i usually get the id using $this->uri->segment(2); how would this change for the possibility of unlimited multiple ids now? thanks

Comment: @user1072983 please add to your post, your current view model and controller's related parts, i think i can give you an answer but it will be very abstract without this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your controller

```
function view() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(1);
    $id_array = explode(",", $id);
    $this->load->model('Site_model');
    foreach ($id_array as $key => $id) {
    // use alphaID function
    $id = alphaID($id ,true);
    if($query = $this->Site_model->get_images($id)) {
        $data['records_array'][$key] = $query;
    // added second array for comparison in view
        $data['id_array'][$key] = $id;
    } 
    }  
    $this->load->view('view', $data);
}
```

For your view:

```
<?php 
foreach ($records_array as $key => $records) {
if(isset($records)) : foreach($records as $row) : ?>
    // removed uri and added array
    <?php if($row->alpha_id == $id_array[$key]):    ?>
        <h1><?php echo $row->alpha_id.$row->file_ext; ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; 
}
?>
```

Comment: you should probably wanna check id's in array numeric or not numeric. You can use is_numeric http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php function.

Comment: well my ids look something like 'i3eD' a-zA-Z0-9

Comment: oh, then is_numeric function is not for you obviously :)

Comment: hi again, this isnt working for me :/ im getting no output
heres my controller function: http://pastebin.com/qjP2MdAQ
and in the view: http://pastebin.com/DSahV1pr

can you see any obvious error? FYI alphaID() converts an alphanumeric id to the real db id

Comment: still no output unless just a single id is in the url, very confused :s

Comment: are you saying same code working without an error for 1 id in the url ?

Comment: @user1072983 it's not working because of this lines for comparison in your view file:     <?php if($row->alpha_id == $this->uri->segment(1)): ?>

btw, i think current version of your code probably not the best way for performance, you may wanna consider rewrite your queries and structure on your own hopefully :)

Comment: i think i see now that the uri seg again needs exploding and another for each? been stuck on this a while now and no expert

Comment: @user1072983 i have edited the answer for second time, you may wanna test it again but not sure it's gonna work or not.

Comment: actually, changed $row->alpha_id to $row->id and it's working!

Comment: how would i output the content of the first id in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Because commas aren't valid path elements you won't be able to get this to work without having your delimited data on the right side of a ? character. You'll need to come up with another scheme or go with the comment from @jprofitt.

Comment: what if i add them to $config['permitted_uri_chars'] ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you can add a comma in `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` but you'll have to manipulate with that segment every time you need it, unless you hook into the system core.

Haven't tested this code but you'll get an idea:

```
<?php

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-,'; // Note a comma...

// Controller
class Blog extends CI_Controller
{

    public function posts($ids = NULL)
    {
        // Check if $ids is passed and contains a comma in the string
        if ($ids !== NULL AND strpos($ids, ',') !== FALSE)
        {
            $ids = explode(',', $ids);
        }

        // Convert $ids to array if it has no multiple ids
        is_array($ids) OR $ids = array($ids);

        // $ids is an array now...

    }

    public function new_posts()
    {
        // Check if $ids is passed and contains a comma in the string
        $ids = $this->uri->segment(1);
        if (!empty($ids) AND strpos($ids, ',') !== FALSE)
        {
            $ids = explode(',', $ids);
        }

        // Convert $ids to array if it has no multiple ids
        is_array($ids) OR $ids = array($ids);

        // $ids is an array now...

    }

}

?>
```

`example.com/index.php/blog/posts/2,4,6,8`

Please note once again, code may not be accurate because I haven't tested it but think it will help you.

Comment: so does ci pass $ids to function posts as a single array with content "2,4,6,8" rather than each id separately, cheers

Comment: Basicly yes... that's what it does. But one note here, it's not a CI, it's you :) You pass "2,4,6,8" as a value of `$ids` argument, at this time this argument is an URI segment too... Take a look at controller docs: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

P.S. From the beginning `$ids` is a string with value "2,4,6,8", only after explode it becomes an array. See updated code above...

Comment: ok got it, and lastly would i still use $this->uri->segment(1) to grab that $ids ?